# Why doesn't my div show when height set to 50% but does when it's set to 500px?

Tags: html, css

Why does the div of the class .topcontainer not show when height:50% (which I assume should take up half of the page) but does when set to 500px? I'm trying to create a responsive page and I'm new to css/html.

Below is height:50%

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px');

body {
 font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: #AA3939;
}

div.container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

div.topcontainer {
 background-image: url("https://scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e35/20633567_1572345419476732_8981370747351990272_n.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 position:relative; 
 width: 100%;
 height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css">
  <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
  <!--<script src="masonScript.js"></script>-->
  <title>majic.photography</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="topcontainer">
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

This just shows the blank background. 
And below this is height:500px.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px');

body {
 font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: #AA3939;
}

div.container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

div.topcontainer {
 background-image: url("https://scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e35/20633567_1572345419476732_8981370747351990272_n.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 position:relative; 
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css">
  <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
  <!--<script src="masonScript.js"></script>-->
  <title>majic.photography</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="topcontainer">
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

This shows the container, but is not responsive and not good on mobile displays.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `height: 50%;` the div has a computed height of zero ... 50% of zero is still zero ... try 50vh if you want half the "viewport" height

Comment: @JaromandaX - minor point of pedantry - the div has computed height of 50%. It has a *used* height of zero. See https://jsfiddle.net/q0dd6e4o/ for a case where this matters,

Comment: True. My wording is not 100% accurate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!
The idea is to place your HTML and body at 100% height then you can use percentage in height.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px');
html,body{width:100%; height:100%;}
body {
 font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: #AA3939;
}

div.container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

div.topcontainer {
 background-image: url("https://scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e35/20633567_1572345419476732_8981370747351990272_n.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 position:relative; 
 width: 100%;
 height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css">
  <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
  <!--<script src="masonScript.js"></script>-->
  <title>majic.photography</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="topcontainer">
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In case you just want the topcontainer to be 50% of your browser's height you could just use

height: 50vh;

instead of 50%. 50vh will make your topcontainer 50% of your browser window's height. 
In addition to that you could add a min-height value of 500px for smaller windows.